# IOS 4.0 code not running on IOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-4.2

I wrote a code on IOS SDK 4.0 and tried running on a device which contains IOS 4.2. I am seeing a empty navigation view. What changes in my code I should do to run it on the target version of SDK.

Comment: Could you add the code you use for presenting the Navigation View?

Comment: This is difficult to diagnose without the code. Do you get any warnings in xCode when building your project?

Comment: No warnings... It loads the application on the device and opens it up. But it do not show my landing page... just a blank navigation view. It works the same way in simulator 4.2 but works fine with 4.0 version.

Comment: This is my nav controller code:                                                                                                                UINavigationController *aHomePageNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aHomePage];
    [window addSubview:[aHomePageNavigationController view]];

Comment: Can you create a new project and copy the code over? Not a great solution but will at least let you know that the SDK is installed properly!

Answer (score 2):

It's very hard to say without having more information on the project and what technologies within iOS it makes use of.  Is there anything in the release notes that sheds light on your problem:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-4_2/

Might be worth checking 4.1 ones as well:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-4_1/

Comment: Seeing the other comments above and the fact it also fails in the simulator I strongly suggest you step through the code with the debugger and po/print every object to make sure they're not null.  My guess is that perhaps aHomePage is null.